# how to configure .npmrc registry order?

Tags: node.js, npm, registry, sinopia

[image]

could someone explain me what exactly going on here.

what is the difference between

registry = http://localhost:4873

vs

http://localhost:4873

why doesn't the default npm registry (registry.npmjs.org) have a similar format at line 1 ?

how to set the priority level - as in I want npm to look first in my local registry and then move onto the public registry.

Does the registry at line 1 have priority over the one at line 4 ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 and 4 aren't registry definitions. They only define the authentication token to be used (as a key-value pair) for your local registry (line 3) and for the default npm registry (line 4).

Line 2 associates the scope *flash* with your local registry. If you for example publish a package with that scope, it will be automatically published to your local registry, using the authentication token specified in line 3.

Comment: hey thanks for that answer !

Do you know the location of the most comprehensive source for helping with npm registry etc ?

like github gists etc for npmrc ? 

thanks for that help btw !